# Selecting Visible Objects Only in Blender 2.8

Tags: selection-tools, visibility

I can't seem to be able to select the visible objects (in object mode) only without selecting the ones hidden behind other objects, toggling X-Ray mode doesn't make any difference.

Just create two objects one smaller than the other and place the small one behind the big one so you can't see it and use the box, circle or lasso selection tool and it will select both objects.

is there a way to use these selection tools without selecting the non visible objects?

Comment: I think this could be considered a bug.

Comment: I have  never heard of such an option in Blender. Has this worked in any version before? It's on by default in Edit Mode, but it does not extend to Object Mode, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I believe @Frederik is right, selection limited by visibility works only in *Edit Mode*. I just tested it in 2.8 and 2.79.